# How do I repair the shut-down/Log-off button?

Tags: 11.10, power-management, shutdown, panel

I use the computer with 2 users.

With one user all works fine.

With the second user account, the shut down and log-off buttons do not work anymore while screen locking standby and hibernation still works.
(i refer to the buttons very right of the top panel).

How can I get back the functionality of log-off and more importantly, shut down?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you provide a screen-shoot of your desktop?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same. Ss a workaround you can create a launcher on the desktop to call:

```
/usr/lib/indicator-session/gtk-logout-helper --shutdown
```

BTW, there are also `--restart` and `--logout` options.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get back the shut down-button in a few seconds is this:

a right mouse click the task bar at the bottom, 2 options will appear, >preferences<, and >about<. Choose >preferences<, then >applets<, then the red circled >shut down<-button, and confirm. That's it! Next time you reboot the original button or buttons will all be there again, instead of the red one, which you can reinstall each time again whenever you should need it.

There are buttons with a similar name, like the green circled >logout<, or the also red circled >quit-logout applet<, just take a look and choose which one suits you.
I never needed any of it, except the >shut down< which seems to please itself in disappearing mysteriously sometimes. But here is the solution to restore peace of mind!

You may also install the nice wheather applet, or terminal-applet on the way!